# export android application for one locale

Tags: android, packaging

I have to maintain an application which has strings, images, videos in different language it makes a heavy apk and I would like to know if I could tell the exporter to only package only resource applying to one specific locale ?

imagine I have the files

```
res/values/strings.xml
res/values-en/strings.xml
res/values-it/strings.xml
res/values-fr/strings.xml
```

And I want to generate and apk with only italian only

```
res/values/strings.xml
res/values-it/strings.xml
```

(and maybe force generated app to use italian as locale)

Actually I have 2 projects for 2 locales us / it, **everthing** is dupplicated, so everytime I have to edit a java or xml file I have to edit it twice.

Now I am required to create a 3rd apps for french and I don't want to copy paste to a new app and to maintain 3 times the same files ! (and more in the future)

I wanted to merge everything into a single apk and then export for one locale because the client require 1 apk per country

I don't know how I could refactor the apps to simplify my works my idea is to export for one locale

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do this with Android Studio and Gradle but it would take some possibly complicated (for a Gradle beginner) setting up of the Source Sets folders.

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors